# malsup jquery form submit on select change

Tags: html, forms, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using Malsup's excellent Form plugin to dynamically load search results onto the same page.

It works great with a standard form submit, however I have 2 select elements in my form and would love for the results to update as the select is changed.

My code at the moment is thus:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target: '#bands-results', 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest 
}; 

$('#bandsearch').ajaxForm(options);

});     
// Show loading message and submit form 
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
$('#bands-results').prepend('<span>Searching</span>');     
    return true; 
}
```

I haven't seen other examples that do the same.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it licked with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#genre-filter").change(function() {
        $("#band_search").submit();
    });

    // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#band_search').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        target: '#band_list',
        success: function() {
            $('#premlim').hide();
        } 
    });

})

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {     
        return true; 
    }
```